# How to release the memory that has been used for a variable in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

How can i release the memory that I used for a variable (e.g. a long string) in C?

Comment: Could use some clarification. Did you dynamically allocate this memory? Or call a library that did it for you? Are you trying to reclaim memory associated with an automatic or static variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you allocated the memory dynamically (using `malloc` or another memory allocator) you free it using `free`. If the memory was statically allocated, you can't free it.

Comment: Curses! Foiled again! Note that some of the standard library functions call malloc or calloc, and leave the responsibility of free the memory to the caller.

Comment: @dmckee: There may be 3rd party or platform APIs that require you to free() a block that they return, but I'm unaware of any standard library functions (other than the allocation ones - malloc, calloc, and realloc) that do this.

Answer (score 2):

This question really cannot be answered without more information.  The only way to know how to free an object (or even know whether or not it should be freed) is to know how the object was allocated.

And when I say object, I mean not just a C++ 'object', but 'object' as is used in the C standard:

> region of data storage in the
>   execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you declare your variable - if it's a regular variable you cant "deallocate" it's memory - it will be released when it gets out of scope like here:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
 int k=i;
 //do stuff
}
```

i will be deallocated when you exit the loop and k will be allocated and deallocated on every pass through the body of the loop.

When it's about runtime memory allocation you can use your trusty malloc and free :)

```
int* intArray;
malloc(200 * sizeof(int));
```

This will give you an array of 200 ints.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't using malloc, and are creating a string or buffer using

```
char array[100];
```

But you know that you're only using it for a very short part of a long function, you can just place that part of the function in another set of { }

```
int reallylongfunction() {
    // Do a lot of stuff
    {
        char stringbuffer[100];
        // Do stuff with the buffer...
        // Ok, we're done with the buffer, and don't want it anymore
    }
    // Do a lot more stuff
    return;
}
```

This will cause the buffer to go out of scope, and be released.  Be careful though, anything else you declare inside the extra { } will go out of scope and disappear as well!

Edit: Damn, comments are right. Static strings going out of scope doesn't do any good. Edited so it's just an array.

Comment: The suggested code will only cause the "string" variable to go out of scope saving you 4 or 8 bytes.  According to the C standard (6.4.5.5), the string's value is an array of static storage duration and is therefore effectively permanently allocated.

Comment: Well you actually have two copies of the string there, and only one of them will be released whend the function returns (_maybe_ sooner). If you just did: static const char mystr[] = "..."; then a decent compiler will just put one version in your code (which will never go away).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at [ustr](http://www.and.org/ustr/), which is a string API that you can use with automatic, constant and dynamicly allocated strings ... only two of which you can actually "free", but all of which you can treat the same way and pass to ustr_free().

You might well still want to learn about how the stack, the heap and data (RO text strings) are "allocated" and "freed" ... but using a usable API while you are learning that will stop help you you a lot (and are going to be much faster than what you'd do on your own).