# Make a variable unusable/unaccessible in scope halfway

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    auto &in = input[i];
    auto &func = functions[i];
    auto &out = output[i];
    // pseudo-code from here:
    unaccessiable(i);
    i = func(in); // error, i is not declared
    out = func(i); // error, i is not declared
    // useful when you mistake in/out for i
}
```

I need to achieve effect that a variable is not accessible or usable after a certain line in the code. (in this code, after the `unaccessiable(i)`)
Specifically I want to disable the iterator of a for's loop.

NOTE: This is only for code correctness, and nothing beyond that. So lambdas (non-compile-time solutions) are just performance hindering.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if you're looking for freeing the memory used by a variable i think **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194428/how-to-release-the-memory-that-has-been-used-for-a-variable-in-c)** would be helpful.

Comment: If you do not want to use the iterator, what the point of your loop? if you want to exit, what about just a break?

Comment: @LeBaptiste I don't want others by mistake to use the loop's iterator in the loop. It happened to us too many times. I still want to do something inside the loop with the variables of it, but just to exclude a few variables.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky uh..but you just removed the loop variable itself. after that, what's the point of running the loop? besides, there's already a provision for that in C++ atleast(if i'm not wrong). if you use the same variable in the loop you'll get compile time error.

Comment: @MridulKashyap Using the variables you extracted using the iterator.

Comment: Loop indexes should be named properly, avoid names like `i`, `j`, `k`... I think you mean you want to prevent loop index variable from being written

Comment: Simple solution: wrap everything below (`unaccessible(i)`) into a function (that will get inlined or not) and don't pass `i` to that function. But I really do not see the point.

Comment: Range based loops could help:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203382.aspx

Comment: This sounds like one of those "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" situations. So don't do that - in this case make it easier to recognize the loop index.  Why don't you pass `in`, `func`, and `out` to a function that does whatever gets done inside the loop?  The fact that you're binding reference variables strongly suggests that you should.

Comment: @Spencer This is a XY problem, ignore the the last line. I just have a problem where a lot of people fails to use the right variable in a few places.

Comment: @MridulKashyap: No

Comment: You can mitigate problems, that you are trying to address here by insisting on using `const` variables and splitting code into smaller functions. Instead of marking variable as non-usable, you will allow use - but as read-only, so it shouldn't hinder refactorizations.

Comment: Using a lambda would *not* have any overhead here in all likelihood. And while Alf’s solution is a really neat trick, it’s really not how you want to write maintainable code (I’ll go further: it’s a huge red warning flag and should be considered an absolute anti-pattern). Restructure your code so that variable lifetime mirrors code structure, don’t hack the code structure into a spaghetti mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to make a name unusable halfway through a block, is to declare it as `struct`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    auto &in = input[i];
    auto &func = functions[i];
    auto &out = output[i];
    // pseudo-code from here:
    struct i;     // ←
    i = func(in); // error, i is a type
    // useful when you mistake out for i
}
```

Alternatively you can put the code after the "here" in a nested block where you can redeclare `i` as a variable of some ungood type, which might give better diagnostics.

Comment: That is the correct answer, inner scope suggested in other answers are wrong.

Comment: Note that this only works in C++, as in C the `struct i` is in different "namespace" (or whatever C standard called it).

Comment: It felt like solutions evolved through time here... I think now this is the best solution. (Though still not 100% clean, but enough)

Comment: @user694733 Why? You are just declaring a incomplete type, it shouldn't find it anywhere else(?)

Comment: Cheers used dictator, it was super-effective. (For future readers: removed C tag) Though I think your solution is compatible for both.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky You cannot refer directly to structure type in C with `i`: you must use `struct i`, unless there is `typedef` for it.

Comment: @user694733 I will check it later, are you referring to old Cs or C11 and newer?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I don't know about ancient implementations, but all standardized C versions should have this property. Latest mention I have seen is in the C11 standard draft N1570, chapter 6.2.3 "Name spaces of identifiers".

Answer (score 2):

One way which comes to mind is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    auto &in = input[i];
    auto &func = functions[i];
    auto &out = output[i];
    {
        struct{} i;
        // ...
        i = func(in); // error
        // useful when you mistake out for i
    }
}
```

The anonymous type won't be compatible with any return type or parameter type. (Except Variadic functions)

(Thanks to LyingOnTheSky for suggesting anonymous structure.)

Comment: Just turn nontype to anonymous struct to accpet(?)

Comment: Well, paying devil's advocate: if i'm the bad/bas... coder and write `i=25` after the inner scope..... ;)

Comment: @LPs yes, the top answer is better (albeit it is based on my answer, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You can put the section that uses `i` into its own block.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < x.size(); counter++) {
    {
        auto i = counter;
        auto &in = input[i];
        auto &func = functions[i];
        auto &out = output[i];
    } // i goes out of scope here
    i = func(in); // error, i is not declared
    // useful when you mistake out for i
}
```

Now `i` is defined only in the inner block.

Comment: Just move in/func/out out of the inner-scope (give them ?\int type).

Comment: My first though but OP wants to do that with loop `counter` variable.

Comment: Not sure that this addresses really OP's concern:  with your solution he'd need to make `counter` unusable if he wants to ensure that nobody can access the looping variable anymore

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact the restriction you want to apply to a loop does not make sense, I would rewrite your loop to ensure noone use the counter by mistake:

```
for(int i = 0;;) //whatever guard 
{
   DoRequiredAction(i);
}
```

Then your `DoRequiredAction` method would not have to modify the loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if applicable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0, j; i < 20; i=++j)
    {
        j=i;

        printf("%d - ", i);

        i = 25;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 16 - 17 - 18 - 19 -
```

As you can see no matter what is done with `i` inside loop scope, due to the backup of `i` value into `j` at the loop start.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

I will not please you, but this is not feasible in the way you expect:

- the preprocessor has an `#undef`, but it's only for preprocessor symbols
- tricking with the preprocessor to redefine i is not realistic either, because it would not affect only the for statement, but everything else (so screw up any future legitimate use of i)
- the ODR prevents to redefine the variable in the scope of the for statement
- as only workaround you could define a sub-bloc as described in use31264's answer AND hope that nobody would screw up your counter outside this bloc.

I understand your hidden requirement from your comment:

> I don't want others by mistake to use the loop's iterator in the loop.
>   It happened to us too many times.

But whatever the approach, the `for` statement is designed in a way that there will ALWAYS be a possibility in the loop to screw the looping variables

### The solution

Fortunately, there could be a solution to prevent this. But you'd have to refactor your code around container based idioms.

You could then opt for a [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which gives NO CHANCE for anybody to intervene in your iterators:

```
for (auto &x :  mycontainer)  {  // where mycontainer is a standard or a custom container
   const auto &in = x.input;     // ok, avoid they srcew up your input as well ;-)
   const auto &func = x.functions;
   auto &out = x.output;
   ...
   // haha : how can anyone screw the iterator now ? :-) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the variable accessible, why create it at all?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<class Item, class Container>
std::size_t calc_offset(Item& item, Container& container)
{
  return std::addressof(item) - std::addressof(*(container.begin()));
}

extern int input[];
extern int output[];
extern int (*functions[])(int);

void test(const std::vector<int>& x)
{
    for (auto& value : x) 
    {
      auto offset = [&x, &value] { return calc_offset(value, x); };

      auto &in = input[offset()];
      auto &func = functions[offset()];
      auto &out = output[offset()];

      out = func(in);

      // won't compile:
      // i = func(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that storing the offset in a local variable actually makes the code more readable in this instance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph how about now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way - rather than use index addressing, use a zip iterator:

This way, after plumbing, the problem may be expressed thus:

```
extern std::vector<int> input;
extern std::vector<int> output;
extern std::vector<int (*)(int)> functions;

void test()
{
    for (auto values : zip(input, functions, output))
    {
      auto &in = std::get<0>(values);
      auto &func = std::get<1>(values);
      auto &out = std::get<2>(values);

      out = func(in); // error, i is not declared
      // won't compile:
      // i = func(in);
    }
}
```

With zip iterators, there's always a philosophical question as to when one 'iterator set' is 'equal' to another. Should it be when one of the iterator pairs is equal (stop on end of shortest sequence) or when they are all equal (demand that all sequences are the same length)?

In this implementation I have used the former - stop iterating when the shortest sequence has been covered. You can tune this by modifying the equality operators of `iterators<>`.

Here's the complete example, including plumbing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>


template<class...Iters>
struct iterators
{
  iterators(Iters... iters) : _iterators { iters... } {}

  bool operator==(const iterators& r) const {
    return !(_iterators != r._iterators);
  }

  bool operator!=(const iterators& r) const {
    return _iterators != r._iterators;
  }

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  auto refs(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    return std::tie(*std::get<Is>(_iterators)...);
  }

  auto operator*() {
    return refs(std::index_sequence_for<Iters...>());
  }

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  auto& plus(std::size_t n, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    using expand = int[];
    void(expand{0,
                ((std::get<Is>(_iterators) += n),0)...
               });
    return *this;
  }

  auto& operator+=(std::size_t n) {
    return plus(n, std::index_sequence_for<Iters...>());
  }

  auto& operator++() {
    return operator+=(1);
  }

  std::tuple<Iters...> _iterators;
};

template<class...Ranges>
auto begins(Ranges&...ranges)
{
  using iters_type = iterators<decltype(std::begin(ranges))...>;
  return iters_type(std::begin(ranges)...);
}

template<class...Ranges>
auto ends(Ranges&...ranges)
{
  using iters_type = iterators<decltype(std::begin(ranges))...>;
  return iters_type(std::end(ranges)...);
}

template<class...Ranges>
struct ranges
{
  ranges(Ranges&...rs)
    : _ranges(rs...)
    {}

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  auto make_begins(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    return begins(std::get<Is>(_ranges)...);
  }

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  auto make_ends(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    return ends(std::get<Is>(_ranges)...);
  }

  auto begin() {
    return make_begins(std::index_sequence_for<Ranges...>());
  }

  auto end() {
    return make_ends(std::index_sequence_for<Ranges...>());
  }

  std::tuple<Ranges&...> _ranges;
};

template<class...Ranges>
auto zip(Ranges&...rs) {
  return ranges<Ranges...>(rs...);
}

extern std::vector<int> input;
extern std::vector<int> output;
extern std::vector<int (*)(int)> functions;

void test()
{
    for (auto values : zip(input, functions, output))
    {
      auto &in = std::get<0>(values);
      auto &func = std::get<1>(values);
      auto &out = std::get<2>(values);

      out = func(in); // error, i is not declared
      // won't compile:
      // i = func(in);
    }
}
```

> Wow, all that code... there must be some processing overhead...

Not if you enable optimisations (gcc 5.3 with -O2):

```
test():
        pushq   %r15
        pushq   %r14
        pushq   %r13
        pushq   %r12
        pushq   %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movq    output+8(%rip), %r15
        movq    functions+8(%rip), %r14
        movq    input+8(%rip), %r13
        movq    input(%rip), %rbx
        movq    functions(%rip), %rbp
        movq    output(%rip), %r12
        jmp     .L4
.L2:
        movl    (%rbx), %edi
        addq    $4, %r12
        addq    $4, %rbx
        call    *0(%rbp)
        addq    $8, %rbp
        movl    %eax, -4(%r12)
.L4:
        cmpq    %rbx, %r13
        jne     .L2
        cmpq    %rbp, %r14
        jne     .L2
        cmpq    %r12, %r15
        jne     .L2
        addq    $8, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r13
        popq    %r14
        popq    %r15
        ret
```